# Is there a way to retrieve data from database if mapped object was changed?

Tags: java, sql, hibernate, oop

I'm using hibernate 5.2. I do not use **hbm2ddl**. Currently trying to make database automatically update when changes to structure were made.

Idea was to get all data from old database and paste it into new database. But I came across issue that I can't retrieve data from changed table. I get error:

```
org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: could not prepare statement
```

Old table was:

```
Fruits{
   int apples;
   int oranges;
}
```

New table:

```
Fruits{
   int apples;
   int oranges;
   int pears;
}
```

New column prevents data from being retrieved.

I was trying to use `TypedQuery`:

```
TypedQuery<Fruits> query = session.createQuery("FROM Fruits", Fruits.class);
ArrayList<Fruits> fruits = (ArrayList<Fruits>) query.getResultList();
```

Is it possible to retrieve object only with old parameters or simply skip parameters that do not match(and put them in map)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know, but you can choose to just select the existing columns in the DB and convert them to an Object with empty pears field.

`SELECT apples, oranges FROM fruits`

That will give you:

```
List<Object[]> fromDB = (ArrayList<Object[]>) query.getResultList();
List<Fruits> fruits = new ArrayList();
for (Object[] o : fromDB) {
    Fruits f = new Fruits(fromDB[0], fromDB[1], 0);
    fruits.add(f);
}
```

(maybe some type conversion is necessary)

Comment: Are you using `createNativeQuery` or `TypedQuery` for this?

Comment: Is there a way I can retrieve pairs of column name + data? So that I know from which column that data comes. So that if pears are located between apples and oranges, I won't put info on oranges into pears.

Comment: I don't think so, but they will come in the order of the database table. So you'll know.

Comment: No, you probably can't use TypedQuery, I would juse use `entityManager.createQuery(String sql)`